# Java regex negation

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have a regex that matches 2 strings, and one not.

```
(^[IVX\.]+.*$)|(^[a-z\\)]+.*$)
```

Test inputs are:

```
a) prueba de inciso   ( find() = true ) 
I. prueba de fraccion ( find() = true )  
Prueba parrafo.       ( find() = false )
```

How i can negate this ? to obtain:

```
 a) prueba de inciso   ( find() = false ) 
I. prueba de fraccion ( find() = false )  
Prueba parrafo.       ( find() = true )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to ensure that the text doesn't start with a certain pattern.

Using `find()` with both anchors (`^$`) is not optimal. Better to use `matches()` without anchors.

You test for numbered list is a bit lenient, so I've made it more strict. Example below shows two extra texts that illustrate this.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?![IVX]+\\.\\s|[a-z]+\\)\\s).*");

System.out.println(p.matcher("a) prueba de inciso").matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher("I. prueba de fraccion").matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher("Prueba parrafo").matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher("I am good").matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher("another test").matches());
```

*Output*

```
false
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead based regex:

```
^(?![IVX.]|[a-z)]).*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY2jI1/2)

`^(?![IVX.]|[a-z)])` is negative lookahead that will fail the match if starting character meet these conditions i.e. character class `[IVX.]` or `[a-z)]`

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to negate the expression, negate the result of `yourMatcher.find()`.

```
Pattern yourPattern = Pattern.compile("^[IVX]+\\.|^[a-z]\\)");
Matcher yourMatcher = yourPattern.matcher("Prueba parrafo. ");
System.out.println(!yourMatcher.find());
                  ^^^^ (negation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way -  `^[^IVX.a-z)].*$`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.